# Why is Paranamer not returning the method names when using CachingParanamer?

Tags: java, parameters, paranamer

I'm trying to use the [paranamer](https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer) library to retrieve the parameter names of my classes.

However, it does not return the parameter name of one method. Here's the class with the method with parameter that I'm trying to return the name:

```java
package domain;

public class DomainTest {
    private String attribute1;
    private int attribute2;

    public DomainTest() {
    }

    public DomainTest(String attribute1, int attribute2) {
        super();
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
    }

    public void someMethod(String paramTest) {
        System.out.println("METHOD IN DOMAIN CLASS");
    }

    public String getAttribute1() {
        return attribute1;
    }

    public int getAttribute2() {
        return attribute2;
    }    
}
```

The method `someMethod`.

And here the class trying to return the parameters' names:

```java
package tests;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer;
import com.thoughtworks.paranamer.Paranamer;
import domain.DomainTest;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> myClass = DomainTest.class;

        System.out.println("CLASS NAME " + myClass.getCanonicalName());

        String[] ParameterNames = null;

        Paranamer paranamer = new CachingParanamer();

        for (Method method : myClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println("METHOD NAME: " + method.getName());
        
            ParameterNames = paranamer.lookupParameterNames(method, false);
        
            if (ParameterNames.length > 0) {
                System.out.println("OK!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO!");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("TESTING!");

        for (int i = 0; i < ParameterNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("PARAMETER NAME " + ParameterNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also seen here that the paranamer class just can get the paramater names with the debug information set using `-g` in `javac` or setting it in the Java compiler in the Eclipse IDE.

I've done this, and it still did not work, not returning the parameter name of the method `someMethod` above. I'm using Paranamer 2.5.2.

How can I get Paranamer to return my method names in this scenario?

Comment: Just a heads up: Accessing parameter names via reflection will be a feature in [Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/features#118).

Comment: @Jeffrey, they said it on 7 too. The paranamer jar really works, but I'm missing something to do it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or you could just annotate your methods and parameters. Not DRY but does work well.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved after a help in a brazilian forum (http://www.guj.com.br)

I have to use the AdaptiveParameter instead CachingParameter, this way:

```
Paranamer paranamer = new AdaptiveParanamer();
```